# Does RedShift Postgresql support Bind variable?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am accessing AWS RedShift through DBI and `DBD::Pg` module in Perl and I have some trouble with SQL bind variable. I call prepare with sql statement (`?` in the place of variable) first and then I call execute with the variable array which needs to be mapped to `?` but it doesn't work. It simply spits "syntax error".

My understanding is that this bind variable needs to be supported by the driver and the database itself so I am not sure whether it is a problem of the driver or RedShift but then I am not sure whether my understanding (bind variable support depends on the driver and underlying database) is correct. If someone could clarify, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared statements are supported, but the correct notation for parameters is $1, $2, ...

From the [Redshift Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html):

> Prepared statements can take parameters: values that are substituted
>   into the statement when it is executed. To include parameters in a
>   prepared statement, supply a list of data types in the PREPARE
>   statement, and, in the statement to be prepared itself, refer to the
>   parameters by position using the notation $1, $2, ... When executing
>   the statement, specify the actual values for these parameters in the
>   EXECUTE statement.